# What's the difference between loadout weapons?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

In Warzone, there are a lot of different loadout options to use. Many of these have very brief one to two sentence descriptions. There are many basic attachments to distinguish these weapons, but some weapons have no attachments listed at all.

My confusion comes into play because there aren't clear distinctions between many of the weapons. Sometimes you'll see weapons with the same attachments listed but one will be of a higher rarity and cost more req points. Other weapons have no attachments listed whatsoever... I'm not sure how to figure out the distinctions between these weapons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Base Weapons**

Assault Rifle - Spray weapon, good damage, good range, best for mid-short range engagements

Battle Rifle/H2BR - Precision weapon, good damage, good range, best for mid range engagements

SMG - Spray weapon, very high damage, very short range, best for close range engagements

DMR - Precision weapon, very high damage, long range, best for long range engagements

Pistol/Magnum - Precision weapon, high damage, close range, best for short-mid engagements.

**Attachments**

Extended mag - Larger magazine and ammo pool

Long Barrel - increased range (crosshair will go red and enable bullet tracking at longer ranges)

Suppressor - you firing won't appear on motion tracker and harder for enemy to hear

stabilization jets - reduced recoil

Laser Pointer - increased accuracy (better bullet tracking)

Kinetic Bolts - increased vehicle damage, increased flinch

energy bayonet - increased melee damage and range (one hit kill in most situations)

hardlight bayonet - increased melee damage and range, increased vehicle damage

**Sights**

Recon - 2x (default on battle rifle)

longshot - 3x (default on DMR)

Sentinel - 4x-6x

Projection - 1.5x (default on Magnum and AR, only SMG can also unlock)

Carbine - 2x (same as Covenant Carbine)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Perhaps I phrased this poorly, but for example you'll see the basic SMG and then other SMGs with no attachments listed... I'm not sure how you're supposed to distinguish between them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean you see your SMG card but you have another SMG card? the attachment it has is a symbol on the lower right of the card, and the sight is appended to the name (Projection SMG with extended mag will have the bullet symbol on the card, but still just be named Projection SMG)

Comment: For example, at level 4 req there's both the basic SMG and the Riot SMG. I don't have it in front of me right now, but the Riot SMG doesn't have an attachment icon nor list one in the description

Comment: Riot SMG? I've never heard or seen that one, and google isn't bringing anything up on it either. It might just be a promotional thing with a special weapon skin on it or something?

Comment: I'll edit in some more info later, but thanks for attempting to answer this poorly asked question!

Comment: Okay so I was totally confused and dumb. This is a good answer though and I think this question has merit so I'll keep it up. Thanks much!

Comment: What was the confusion?

Comment: I had misread several of the descriptions. I am still curious if there is a noticeable difference in damage between the same base weapon but two different req levels (i.e. base AR versus 8point one), but that's almost a different question